# О неисполнимых указаниях

Tags: семантика

Предположим, что на столике лежат туз, король, дама и валет.

Верно ли, что:

- указание "Возьми туза, и не бери туза." неисполнимо,
- указание "Возьми туза, и не бери туза." ("Take the ace, and don't take the ace.") означает высказывание "Ты не вправе брать туза." ("You may not take the ace.")?

P.S. Желающие могут рассмотреть вопрос об использовании неисполнимых указаний для дезорганизации деятельности роботов (например, боевых).

P.P.S. Кроме того, желающие могут попытаться найти ответ на вопрос, почему жители Соединённого королевства употребляют "must not" и "cannot" гораздо чаще, чем "may not".

Comment: Полководец! А зачем в Армию призваны король, дама и валет? Чтобы дезорганизовать деятельность боевого робота?

Comment: Прочитано.

Answer (score 1):

Робот возьмет туза и будет отдыхать по случаю отсутствия второго.

Comment: Конгениально.

Comment: "Это конгениально! Хорошо бы и на ордера посмотреть".  И почему это все великие комбинаторы так любят это слово?